# Using NSView in NSTableView?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa, storyboard

I have searched a lot and but I am not able to find solution for my problem. Seems it is very easy for everyone.

I am trying to create a NSTableView which have NSView cells. But those NSViews will be complicated so I decided to use separate NSViewController for these NSViews so that I can handle actions separately.
Here is what I have done-

This is My StoryBoard-
[image]

I am trying to use ViewController for each of cells in NSTableView.
This View is very simple currently(only two labels) but there will be few buttons and image views in future.
the view controller have identifier "rowCell".
I have did this-

```
extension CMCenterTableViewController:NSTableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return self.conversationData.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
    {
        var centralStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var rowCellID: AnyObject? = centralStoryBoard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("rowCell")
        var castedView = rowCellID as! CMRowCellView
        castedView.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.minX, self.view.frame.minY, self.view.frame.width, 75)
        (castedView as CMRowCellView).SubjectLable.stringValue = (conversationData[row].valueForKey("subject") as? String)!

        (castedView as CMRowCellView).FromLable.stringValue = (conversationData[row].valueForKey("fromAddress") as? String)!
        return castedView . view

    }



}
```

This is viewController -

```
import Cocoa

class CMRowCellView: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var FromLable: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var SubjectLable: NSTextField!
    var from:String?
    var subject:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

This works Ok but there is slowness in scroll because views are loaded each time and they are not being reused.
My problem is I want to reuse these view with makeViewWithIdentifier, But I can't find a way to do so.

And also Is it correct way to use view controllers in NSTableView?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the table's subviews are best though of as owned by the table view, and share the same controller as the table view.  The "controller" being the class that implements NSTableViewDelegate and NSTableViewDatasource.  Target-action from the controls in the cells can indeed get complicated.

Comment: So you suggest this approach is not good? If cells of table can be different views with different controls then using separate controllers will be good Idea IMO.

Comment: Controllers which don't "own" the cell views because the table does.  You probably need a custom view+controller *within* a **generic** cell view.  Or perhaps you generate specific cell views in the delegate, but the view controller owns a subview which covers the entire cell.

Comment: "You probably need a custom view+controller within a generic cell view">> I am not sure I understand you correctly but That is what I am doing currently right?